# Wall air conditioner not operating with outlet

Tags: walls, air-conditioning

I recently bought a Haier 12000 btu wall ac unit. When plugged into the wall outlet a 15A 125V, the unit turns on for a few second then cuts off with the units display lights flashing. This unit doesn't need a 220line so I plugged it into a surge protector strip then to the wall outlet. The unit fired up and began to operate with no problems. So, I'm confused with the wall outlet which the unit recommended the 15a 125v outlet. What should I try next???

Comment: Does the manual give any error code information to go with the A/C's blinkenlights of protest?  Also, what model is this?

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy answer with the information provided. It is new Take it back!. This the best advice I can give as a licensed electrician, & having universal HVAC licencees. If additional information of the model and a better description of flashing lights we may be able to give a better answer.

Comment: +1. IDK WTF is going on here. *Reject.*